# why dotnet test --collect requires obj folder

Tags: dotnet-cli, coverlet, dotnet-test

I have two projects in my solution, a class library and a test library (lets call them `Library` and `Tests.Library`).

My library project targets `.NETStandard2.0` and my test project is based on the visual studio `NUnit` project template (using coverlet), and targets `.Net 6`.

In summary, due to a dockerized ci-pipeline, I am doing the following:

- dotnet build
- dotnet publish -o Publish --no-build
- remove all bin and obj folders
- dotnet test Publish/Tests.*.dll --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"

The tests runs successfully and a coverage file is created as expected (`TestResults\{guid}\coverage.cobertura.xml`), but it is empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<coverage line-rate="0" branch-rate="0" version="1.9" timestamp="1682064358" lines-covered="0" lines-valid="0" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0">
  <sources />
  <packages />
</coverage>
```

If I keep `Library\obj` folder, the file contains the expected coverage data.

Why do I need to keep the `Library\obj` and is there a way to get rid of it?